# Get array value using a string as the array name and indexes

Tags: php

I am trying to send specific indexes from arrays by string to some php code to describe the data that I need to combine. The problem I am having is that SESSION does not seem to be available within the function Str_To_Array. What am I missing about scope here? Also if anybody can recommend a better way I would be every so grateful. PS i added the include in case including the function causes any abnormalities.

```
function Str_To_Array($str) {

    $d = explode(':',$str) ;

    print_r($d[0]) ;

    $t = $d[0] ;

    $n = $$t ;

    if( !isset( $d[1] ) ) { return $n ; }

    $n = $n[$d[1]] ;

    return $n ;
}

include(DIR_ROOT . "php_function/Str_To_Array.php") ;

$test = '_SESSION' ;
$ARRANGE = Str_To_Array($test) ;<----this says _SESSION is undefined
print_r($ARRANGE) ;
$ARRANGE = $$test ;<----this works
print_r($ARRANGE) ;
```

Comment: Have you added session_start() on top of your script?

Comment: Yea. I was wondering if that had something to do with it as well, thats why I asked the question if maybe it is outside the scope. It is defined when I just use $ARRANGE = $$test.

Comment: Don't use variable variables - they bring troubles.

Comment: Not sure why youre doing that Str_To_Array function, but you can add `global $$t;` after `$t = $d[0];` line.

Comment: i need to order data in session by dates and add markers for missing time periods. The data is stored across different session indexes. The specific pages use different indexes but differently share each others data. I wanted to just send a string with the post data that told the server what indexes to use to combine.

Comment: Well, the first thing I noticed is that you're assigning a string to `$test`, so instead of passing the `$_SESSION` object to your `Str_To_Array` function, you're passing a string that won't even get exploded in the first line of that function because there's no `:` characters delimiting anything... which makes the purpose of that function muddy at best.

Comment: ultimately i was gonna send the string in the form arrayname:index1:index2 etc that was jsut for testing purpose. The str_to-array doesnt iterate either for simplicity. I have just gone with using a file to store the info though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to follow the purpose here, however this should work

```
function getVar($str)
{
    $vars = get_defined_vars();
    $d = explode(':',$str) ;
    if (isset($vars[$d[0]]) || array_key_exists($vars[$d[0]])) {
        if (!empty($d[1]) && (isset($vars[$d[0]][$d[1]]) || array_key_exists($vars[$d[0]][$d[1]]))
            return $vars[$d[0]][$d[1]];
        return $vars[$d[0]];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Interesting work around. I tried finding _SESSION registered in Globals but it wouldnt transfer either. This makes it work though. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It loos like it's the problem of PHP, just tried the code below, when in a function, `${'_SESSION'}` works and `$$t` don't work. This only happens to `$_SESSION` but not the other super global `$_POST` and `$_GET` etc.

```
<?php
session_start();

function foo() {
  $t = '_SESSION';
  $a = $$t;             // not work
  $b = ${'_SESSION'};   // works
  var_dump($a, $b);
}

foo();
```

Comment: Wow thats interesting. I normally assume its something Im doing wrong. This is the issue though. I guess I have no way to accomplish this then. Thanks for clearing it up.